# Lua weak reference

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm aware of the weak tables functionality in Lua, however I would like to have a weak reference with a single variable.

I've seen [this proposal](http://www.lua.org/notes/ltn006.html) which suggests an API as follows:

```
-- creation
ref = weakref(obj)
-- dereference
obj = ref()
```

which would seem ideal. However this doesn't appear to be in the documentation elsewhere; only weak tables.

Is there something analogous to Python's [weak reference to object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref) functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to do here ultimately? You can emulate this yourself using a table with at metatable I believe (or with `newproxy` and a metatable) if you really need to.

Comment: I'm using middleclass for OO, passing a closure from objA to objB. When objA goes out of scope, the closure is preventing both instances from being GC'd because it contains a reference to objA. Never heard of newproxy before, going to google it up...

Comment: hmmm.. "The undocumented newproxy function was removed in Lua 5.2, since it was made redundant by other features added in that version" from http://lua-users.org/wiki/HiddenFeatures

Comment: Yeah, you don't need it for this it was just to use a userdata instead of a table for the idea. The idea was a table with a metatable which supported `__call` to get you the `ref()` syntax where either the table itself or the metatable were weak and held the reference.

Comment: Interesting.. I've not used metatables too much with Lua. I'll have a read to see if there's something useful there. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the metatable for the weak-ref idea. Without it you just need to use `ref.real` or `ref.obj` or whatever instead of `ref()`.

Comment: "this proposal" is a document from 2004, before you could (I presume) create weak tables directly in Lua (i.e., without using the C API). That's no longer the case nowadays. You got two good answers showing you how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this can do what you want I believe:

```
local obj = {value = "obj.value"}

local ref = setmetatable({real = obj}, {__mode = "v", __call = function(self) return self.real end})

print(obj.value)
print(ref.real.value)
print(ref().value)

obj = nil
collectgarbage()
collectgarbage()

print(obj)
print(ref.real)
print(ref())
```

The `__call` part is optional but gives you the `ref()` call syntax. Without it you have to use the direct access version.

Answer (score 10):

When lua does not provide something, there is often a simple way to implement it from the other primitives.

```
function weakref(data)
    local weak = setmetatable({content=data}, {__mode="v"})
    return function() return weak.content end
end
```

We create a weak table with just the data in it. Then we return a function that when called, returns the contents of that table.

(Note, weak references may not be broken until garbage collection, and literals are never garbage collected.)

Comment: It's a shame this answer wasn't accepted - it's better than the accepted one, AND came about a minute sooner.

Comment: The other answer has some pretty important things going for it... specifically, it has the potential to create less garbage, since my solution creates an object and a closure over that object for each call, while the accepted solution only creates the table. (Both also spuriously create a new metatable each time as well, but that could be pulled out and reused).

Comment: Ah, good points. Mostly I just needed to learn about `__mode="v"` - in my use case I'm making an image pool and just wanted a weak table where all the values in a table were collectable.